# Check if a String can be created by linking elements in a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, concatenation

I want to check whether a String can be created by linking elements in a given list, and what that concatenation is.
For example:

```
String = 'BIBER'
List = ['BI', 'BIB', 'BIBE', 'BE', 'BER', 'ER']
```

'BIBER' can be built out of 'BI' and 'BER',

so the program should return TRUE and a list with the components:

```
components = ['BI','BER']
```

I have already tried this, but I can't check what the components are:

```
r = re.compile("(?:" + "|".join(List) + ")*$")
    if r.match(Word) != None:
        print('TRUE')
```

Comment: And `BIB` and `ER` presumably?

Comment: one concatenation is sufficient

Comment: If you only had one element in `List` (maybe such as `BI`) - is it desired it could match BIBI/BIBIBI etc... ?

Comment: yes, the elements in a list can be used more than once

Comment: could `List` contain one char as an item, like `['E', 'B', ...]` ?

Comment: Do you mean in the same order as the list of components or in any order?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do brute force:

```
s = 'BIBER'
li = ['BI', 'BIB', 'BIBE', 'BE', 'BER', 'ER']

import itertools as it

for i in range(2,len(li)+1):
    for t in it.permutations(li, i):
        if ''.join(t)==s:
            print t
```

Prints:

```
('BI', 'BER')
('BIB', 'ER')
```

If you want to test whether some group of sub strings can be completely combined to equal a string:

```
def builds(s, componts):
    return any(s==''.join(t) for t in it.permutations(componts))  

>>> builds(s, ('R','BE','I','B'))
True
```

This does not handle reusing different substrings more than once (such as `('B','I','E','R')`) For that, you might consider using a Trie.

Answer (score 0):

## Using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)...

This function should do the job:

```
def check(String, List):
    return String in [a+b for a,b in itertools.combinations(List, 2)]
```

Which returns `True` for your input of:

```
check('BIBER', ['BI', 'BIB', 'BIBE', 'BE', 'BER', 'ER'])
```